# Copying asset by insertFileByLocalPath() results in fopen:()failed to open stream error

Tags: plugin-development, assets, error

EDIT: Updated code (issue remains)

I'm trying to implement functionality in a plugin that, when saving an entry with a lightswitch enabled, takes the asset at `index 0` from an assetfield called `useruploads`, copies that asset, applies some watermark to it via php and finally saves that new copied asset back to the assetfield.

It all seems to work except when I get to the part where the new copied image is actually saved.

```
$originalFile = "naja"."-copyright.".$asset->extension;

$copyrightedImage = craft()->assets->insertFileByLocalPath(
     $tempPath,
     $originalFile,
     $myAssetFolderId,
     AssetConflictResolution::KeepBoth
);
```

When saving an entry, craft throws the following error at me:

> fopen(https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/irl.x-challenge.info/challenges/naja-copyright170725090818.JPG): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

I doubt it actually is a directory-permission thing, since I write to CRAFT_STORAGE_PATH which works just fine with another function without giving me any permission related error.

I am fairly new to writing any sort of plugin for any CMS, so I'd appreciate the help.

The full code is the following:

```
    $fileIds = array();

    $event = $myEvent;
    static $recursionLevel = 0; // is set only once

    if ($recursionLevel == 0 ) {

            $recursionLevel++;

            $entry = $event->params['entry'];
            $asset = $entry->useruploads[0];

            $imageInfo = pathinfo($asset->url);
            $tempPath = CRAFT_STORAGE_PATH.'runtime/temp/'.$imageInfo['basename'];
            file_put_contents($tempPath, fopen($asset->url, 'r'));


            $myAssetFolderId = 27;

            $currentUser = craft()->userSession->getUser();

            // insert the file into assets
            array_push($fileIds, $asset->id);

            // switchcase for different file formats
            switch(strtolower($asset->extension)){
                case 'jpg':
                case 'jpeg':
                    $im = @ImageCreateFromJPEG ($tempPath);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    $im = @ImageCreateFromPNG ($tempPath);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }


            $text = chr(169)." x-challenge backstage | ".$currentUser->getFriendlyName().$asset->id;
            // Prepare font size and colors
            $text_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 65);
            $bg_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 80);
            $font = CRAFT_BASE_PATH. "../public/fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf";
            $font_size = 10;
            $assetHeight = craft()->assets->getFileById($fileIds[0]);
            $scaleFactor = ($assetHeight->getWidth()/1000);
            $font_size = $font_size*$scaleFactor;

            // Set the offset x and y for the text position
            $offset_x = 0;
            $offset_y = 20;

            // Get the size of the text area
            $dims = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $text);
            $text_width = $dims[4] - $dims[6] + $offset_x;
            $text_height = $dims[3] - $dims[5] + $offset_y;

            $text_pos_y = imagesy($im) - $font_size;
            imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, $text_pos_y+($font_size/2), $text_width+$font_size, $text_pos_y-($font_size+($font_size/2)), $bg_color);

            // Add text
            imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $offset_x+5, $text_pos_y, $text_color, $font, $text);

            switch(strtolower($asset->extension)){
                case 'jpg':
                case 'jpeg':
                    imagejpeg($im, $tempPath);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    imagepng($im, $tempPath);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            // save back to S3
            //$originalFile = $imageInfo["filename"]."-".md5($currentUser->id)."-copyright.".$asset->extension;
            $originalFile = "naja"."-copyright.".$asset->extension;

            $copyrightedImage = craft()->assets->insertFileByLocalPath(
                $tempPath,
                $originalFile,
                $myAssetFolderId, // notice, this is the id of the folder you want to upload to
                AssetConflictResolution::KeepBoth
            );

            if ($copyrightedImage->isSuccess()){
                //$fileIds[] = $copyrightedImage->getDataItem('fileId');
                array_push($fileIds, $copyrightedImage->getDataItem('fileId'));
            }
```